# How to find the User-Agent of an app, and use it in a desktop browser?

Tags: user-agent

I am trying to find the user-agent for an android app.

The app allows in-app browsing, so I'm thinking it must have a user-agent for browsing.

How do I find out what that is? *I'm trying to use that information to run the desktop version of the website so that it looks as if I am operating the app.*

Comment: This may help. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [this useragent database](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_type_specific/in-app-browser/). They have over 38 million user-agents and even a search engine to find the app you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome - User Agent Strings](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#webview_user_agent)

From WebView on Android section

> The Android 4.4 (KitKat) Chromium-based WebView adds Chrome/*version* to the user agent string.

Old WebView UA:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; en-gb; Build/KLP) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30

WebView UA in KitKat to Lollipop

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 5 Build/*BuildID*) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
>
> If you’re attempting to differentiate between the WebView and Chrome for Android, you should look for the presence of the Version/*X.X* string in the WebView user-agent string. Don’t rely on the specific Chrome version number (for example, 30.0.0.0) as the version numbers changes with each release.

WebView UA in Lollipop and Above

> In the newer versions of WebView, you can differentiate the WebView by looking for the wv field as highlighted below.
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36

NB. In-app web access is not limited to default in-app browser, these are one of UAs.

Try google with key word "android browser UA". Many samples can be found like [Android Browser User Agents](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/android-browser/)

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome can mimicry to phones/tablets. 
[image]

Comment: I am ware of that. I was just curious if an app was using a very specific User-Agent. This is because my XHR get requests are not getting through the desktop browser even after changing the user agent, but they get through from the app.